# Scrolling down to a position with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

Hi just a quick doubt that's driving me mad.

I'm trying to automaticly scroll down to an button when this button is clicked.

I've got the y-index value of my button saved on a variable called scrollIndex (thanks to the offset() method).

And now I'm trying to scroll down my window with this:

```
var scrollIndex = $('#tourbutton').offset();
$("body").animate({scrollTop:(scrollIndex.top)},500,"linear");
```

I've actually tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work and I supose it's because I'm making a wrong use of the scrollTop method()..

Any help ? Thank you!

My full code:

```
window.onload = initAll; 

function initAll() { 
    changeStyle(); 
    $('#tourbutton').click = hello(); 
} 

function hello() { 
    var scrollIndex = $('#tourbutton').offset(); 
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:(scrollIndex.top)},800,"swing"); 
    //var scrollIndex = $('#tourbutton').offset();     
    //$("window").scrollTo({top:scrollIndex},800); 
}
```

SOLVED! I just wrote everything inside click() like this:

```
function initAll() {
$('#tourbutton').click(function() {

var scrollIndex = $('#tourbutton').offset();
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:(scrollIndex.top)},800,"swing");

//var scrollIndex = $('#tourbutton').offset();
//$("window").scrollTo({top:scrollIndex},800);
});

    changeStyle();
}
```

And everything works now except I don't quite understand why... if somebody understands why I cannot link the click eventHandler to an external function I'll be glad to know the answer.

Thanks to all!

Comment: Try `$('document').animate({scrollTop:(scrollIndex.top)},500,"linear");`?

Comment: [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Comment: hmm I wrote this: var scrollIndex = $('#tourbutton').offset();
 $("window").scrollTo({top:scrollIndex},800); and I get and error "$("window").scrollTo is not a function"

Comment: So probably you've link script incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you testing in Chrome? I ran into another SO question at some point where if you specified a body height of 100% in Chrome then setting scroll position didn't work. You had to either put the body of your site in a scrollable div or not specify 100% height.

Try this:

```
var scrollIndex = $('#tourbutton').offset();
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:(scrollIndex.top)},500,"linear");
```

Comment: I did what you said and now it works but it does it everytime I load my page! My full code is like this:

Comment: window.onload = initAll;

function initAll() {
 changeStyle();
 $('#tourbutton').click = hello();
}

function hello() {
 
 var scrollIndex = $('#tourbutton').offset();
 $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:(scrollIndex.top)},800,"swing");

 //var scrollIndex = $('#tourbutton').offset();
 //$("window").scrollTo({top:scrollIndex},800);
}